# d3.js: Getting the new (x,y) coordinates of each bar as the chart is zoomed/dragged

Tags: d3.js, bar-chart

I am using the basic and very useful D3 bar chart with zoom/pan functionality presented at http://jsfiddle.net/9rypxf10/

I am having difficulty retrieving the new (x,y) coordinates (lower left corner) of each individual bar as the chart is zoomed and/or dragged. How can I display (x,y) in the zoom() function:

```
function zoom() {
...
}
```

Comment: What are you hoping to do with the coordinates - it could help in demonstrating a solution and would clarify if the solution is relevant.

Comment: Actually my objective is to display (x,y) coordinates onmouseover anywhere within each rectangle.